# Deleting node using address of previous node

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a method called Find, which, when the user enters the value of an element, the address gets saved in a new Node called *npt.

Using *npt as an argument, I am supposed to create a delete method which removes the value after the value saved in npt.

For example, if this is my list:
134, 564, 674, 253,and I enter 674 for Find, then 253 gets deleted.

Currently, this is my code for the delete function:

```
void LinkedList::Delete(Node *PrePosition){
Node *temp = PrePosition -> next;
PrePosition->next = PrePosition->next->next;
delete temp;
}
```

The problem with this though, is that there is no way to delete the head node currently.  The only hint I was given, which does not really help me is this:
PrePosition is NULL if you want to delete the head of the list.

Comment: Presumably the `LinkedList` class has a `Node *` pointer called `head` which links the head of the list. So if you get a `NULL` for your argument, then execute the same code using the head pointer.

Comment: This will probably sound incredibly dumb on my part, but the Find method requires an int. How would it be possible to set the argument to NULL?

Comment: @Bob You can return `-1` if your code allows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have to do a recursive version.
Make a condition for Head. In Find:

```
Node* find(T value){
    if (head->value == value)
        return nullptr;
    return find(head->next);
```

Now in Delete:

```
void Delete(Node * pre) {
    Node* temp;
    if (pre == nullptr) {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
    } else {
        temp = pre->next;
        pre->next = pre->next->next;
    }
    delete temp;
}
```

Comment: Is this method supposed to make it so that any value I put in which is not a node deletes the head? It seems like it is leaving room for errors in case of typos.

Comment: If you pass in a nullptr, the head gets deleted. If you don't want that to be the case, make a delete head function. This Delete function should be private, so the only person who'd be making the typo is you...